# FileOutputStream write non-existent bytes

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I have a problem with FileOutputStream.

I use this simple code:

```
byte[] data1 = BD25Writer.getData1();
byte[] data2 = BD25Writer.getData2();

FileOutputStream dbf = new FileOutputStream(new File(file.getPath(), "file1.dbf"));
dbf.write(data1);
dbf.close();

FileOutputStream dbt = new FileOutputStream(new File(file.getPath(), "file2.dbt"));
dbt.write(data2);
dbt.close();
```

File is written correctly on most platforms (Windows, Android). In HEX-editor it looks like this:
[image]

But on only one device (YotaPhone2, model:YD201, android 6.0.1) this code with the same bytes is not working properly. Non-existent bytes written to the file:

[image]

Methods .getData1() and .getData2() works correctly. These methods simply write float data into an array of bytes. Сode looks like this:

```
private static byte[] getData1(){
    int key = ...;
    float[] buffer = new float[]{...};
    byte[] array = new byte[buffer.length * 4];
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(buffer[i]).array();
        array[key + i * 4] = bytes[3];
        array[key + i * 4 + 1] = bytes[2];
        array[key + i * 4 + 2] = bytes[1];
        array[key + i * 4 + 3] = bytes[0];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Before sending array to FileOutputStream an array looks like this (get from debug):

[image]

How can this be and how can I fix this ?

Comment: Isn't the `0D 0A` the code for CR/LF? Are you certain the `byte[]` from `getData()` does not have these entries?

Comment: My guess is that the FileOutputStream is working correctly, and those 0D bytes are in the data. You should [edit] your question to include the relevant parts of this BD25Writer class, and show where the data is ultimately coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a little more information. I certain the byte[] from getData() is correct. Checked the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, all code works correctly. Mail client broke the file during sending.