# FileOutputStream change `0A` byte to `0D 0A`

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I convert `float` to `byte[]` array with this code:

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(number).array();
```

For example if I put the number `0.02f` I get the bytes `[60,-93,-41,10]`
Then I try to write this `byte[]` to file with this code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(bytes);
dbf.close();
```

On most platform in HEX-editor this file looks like this: `3C A3 D7 0A`. But on special device same code gives this: `3C A3 D7 0D 0A`. Before each `0A` `0D` appears.

I know than `0A` is a `LF` and `0D 0A` is a `CRLF` but I do not know how this can be.

With what it can be connected ?

Comment: IX Operation Systems uses '0A'  as End of line and Windows '0D 0A'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776923/how-can-i-normalize-the-eol-character-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like when the data is transferred to your "special device" it is being translated as if it was a text file.  This will corrupt the file in the manner you see. e.g. FTP has a text transfer mode which does this.

You shouldn't confuse text and binary. You are writing a binary format and if you read it as a binary format, new lines are not relevant.

Don't read it as text as it's not text and you won't have a problem.

Comment: @VictorChurilov Still, Peter is right. Somewhere your file is being treated as if it is a text file instead of as a binary file. How are you sending it to the "special device"? Using FTP? Are you using binary transfer mode? Is there something else that treats the file as if it is a text file?

Comment: That "Special device" (Android 6.0.1) generate that bad file with that simple code. Other devices use that code and genegate file without `0D`

Comment: @VictorChurilov Can you add `System.out.println("length= " + file.length());` immediately after writing in the code to confirm the file now has 5 bytes? (Assuming file is a `File`)

Comment: This question is a simplification of the actual problems which can not solve by my colleague - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499255/fileoutputstream-write-non-existent-bytes ;I can add that `System.out.println` to real code. I need a few minutes.

Comment: `bytes` and `file` give same length

Comment: I found the trouble. The mail client breaks the file when sending. My bad. Thank you very much!